# SAS_Conditional Cumulative Sum

Tags: sas

My question is about the conditional cumulative sum in SAS. I think it can be explained better by using sample. I have following dataset:

```
Date                 Value
01/01/2001          10
02/01/2001          20
03/01/2001          30
04/01/2001          15
05/01/2001          25
06/01/2001          35
07/01/2001          20
08/01/2001          45
09/01/2001          35
```

I want to find the cumulative sum of value. My condition is if cumulative sum more than 70, it should be 70 and the next cumulative sum should be began from the excessive value over 70 and so on.. More preciesly, my new data should be:

```
Date                 Value    Cumulative 
01/01/2001           10        10
02/01/2001           20        30
03/01/2001           30        60
04/01/2001           15        70
05/01/2001           25        30 ( 75-70=5+25=30)
06/01/2001           35        65
07/01/2001           20        70
08/01/2001           45        60  ( 85-70=15+45=60)
09/01/2001           35        95   ( because its last value)
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, although there is bound to be one more elegant. It's split into two parts with `if eof` to satisfy the last observation condition.

```
data want;
  set test end = eof; 

  if eof ^= 1 then do;

    if cumulative = 70 then cumulative = extra;

    Cumulative + value;
    extra = cumulative - 70;

    if extra > 0 then do;
      cumulative = 70;
    end;
  end;

  retain extra;
  retain cumulative;

  if eof = 1 then cumulative + value;

run;
```

Comment: There might be a more elegant one, but I really like yours. It also handles conditions the OP did not mention, like remainders > 70, so the extra needs to be pushed down to multiple lines (maybe as far as the last line).